# Implement functions from other class files C++

Tags: c++, function, class

So I'm a little new with C++, and our teacher hasn't gotten to the point of telling us how to use functions from separate class files.

Right now we're just doing text based stuff, but I have it where it randomly picks an enemy type and enemy from arrays. This is the function that's in the separate class file "enemy.cpp"

In the "main.cpp" I want to call this function. (I thought it would be something like "enemy.genRandEnemy()" but it's not working).

Here's the code for the enemy class -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class enemy{
    public:
        void genRandEnemy();
};

void genRandEnemy() {

    string enemy[] = {"dragon", "troll", "wolf", "wraith", "spider", "scorpion", "hydra", "snake", "reaper", "centipede", "worm"};
    string enemyType[] = {"hell", "ice", "soul eater", "bone", "carnivorous"};

    srand(time(0)); 
    int randomEnemy = rand();
    int randomEnemyType = rand();

    int randEnemy = (randomEnemy % 11);
    int randEnemyType = (randomEnemyType % 5);

    if(randEnemyType == 0){cout << enemyType[0];} 
    else if(randEnemyType == 1){cout << enemyType[1];} 
    else if(randEnemyType == 2){cout << enemyType[2];}
    else if(randEnemyType == 3){cout << enemyType[3];}
    else if(randEnemyType == 4){cout << enemyType[4];}

    cout << " ";

    if(randEnemy == 0){cout << enemy[0];}
    if(randEnemy == 1){cout << enemy[1];}
    if(randEnemy == 2){cout << enemy[2];}
    if(randEnemy == 3){cout << enemy[3];}
    if(randEnemy == 4){cout << enemy[4];}
    if(randEnemy == 5){cout << enemy[5];}
    if(randEnemy == 6){cout << enemy[6];}
    if(randEnemy == 7){cout << enemy[7];}
    if(randEnemy == 8){cout << enemy[8];}
    if(randEnemy == 9){cout << enemy[9];}
    if(randEnemy == 10){cout << enemy[10];}
}
```

and here's the code snip from the main class --

```
cout << "Then out comes three " << enemy.genRandEnemy() << "s and they encircle you. ";
```

Also in the main class, i have up where the includes are -- #include "enemy.cpp"

I don't think i have the enemy class set up right to do this and i'm not sure how.

Comment: There are no class files in C++. `void genRandEnemy()` defines a global function, you probably wanted to define `void enemy::genRandEnemy()`.

Comment: oh.. well i did it, and still didn't work..

it said in the error log --
[Error] expected primary-expression before '.' token --

that "." is right where "enemy.genRandEnemy()" is

Comment: Your full program please. Also, you don't (typically) include source files in other source files; you just make the names of classes, functions etc. defined in one source file known to other source files by including *just* their declaration. That's why you separate things into header files (just the declarations) and source files (where the definitions reside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your splitting of code into several files is unfortunate. You should put the *declaration* of types and functions you wish to use in more than one file into a *header file*. Therefore, create the file `enemy.hpp` and put `enemy`'s declaration in it:

```cpp
class enemy
{
public:
  void genRandEnemy();
};
```

Put the *definition* of functions into a separate *source file* and name it `enemy.cpp`.  It will look like this:

```cpp
#include "enemy.hpp"
#include <iostream>
// All your other includes needed to define the function...

void
enemy::genRandEnemy()
{
  // Implementation of the function...
}
```

Then, in any file that needs to call `enemy::genRandEnemy`:

```cpp
#include "enemy.hpp"

void
f()
{
  enemy foe;
  foe.genRandEnemy();
  // Or whatever...
}
```

Note that your code is inconsistent: You *declare* `genRandEnemy` as a *member function* of class `enemy` but *define* it as a free function outside any class.  My example always puts it as a member of `enemy`.  (This actually seems weired to me.  A function with that name would be supposed to *create* a new enemy and *return* it. If it is a member of `enemy`, I will need an `enemy` ahead of time to create one.)

Two other remarks:

- You are re-seeding the random generator every time the `genRandEnemy` function is called.  This will make for a poor randomness.
- I'm sure you can come up with a better solution than the pile of `if(randEnemy == 1) { cout << enemy[1]; }`.  Can you?

Comment: yeah i know using the random thing i have now is not good, but for now it'll have to do til i get further into this C++ book in my class.

And yeah, i used the code from the person below with the compacting the 'if(randEnemy == 1) {cout << enemy[1];}' i just used that for temp since i didn't feel like figuring out how to compact it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This is your class:

```
class Enemy{ //I change it to not confuse with the local variable in genRandEnemy.
    public:
        void genRandEnemy(); //you should return a string instead of the printing
};
```

the function prototype is:

```
void Enemy::genRandEnemy() {
...
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
int main()
{
   Enemy e;//declare a variable
   //now you use the variable:
   cout << "Then out comes three ";
   e.genRandEnemy();
   cout << "s and they encircle you. ";
   return 0;
}
```

BTW:

you can short your code:

```
 if(randEnemyType == 0){cout << enemyType[0];} 
 else if(randEnemyType == 1){cout << enemyType[1];} 
 else if(randEnemyType == 2){cout << enemyType[2];}
 else if(randEnemyType == 3){cout << enemyType[3];}
 else if(randEnemyType == 4){cout << enemyType[4];}
```

can be replaced by:

```
 cout<<enemyType[randEnemyType];
```

And the same:

```
 if(randEnemy == 0){cout << enemy[0];}
 if(randEnemy == 1){cout << enemy[1];}
 if(randEnemy == 2){cout << enemy[2];}
 if(randEnemy == 3){cout << enemy[3];}
 if(randEnemy == 4){cout << enemy[4];}
 if(randEnemy == 5){cout << enemy[5];}
 if(randEnemy == 6){cout << enemy[6];}
 if(randEnemy == 7){cout << enemy[7];}
 if(randEnemy == 8){cout << enemy[8];}
 if(randEnemy == 9){cout << enemy[9];}
 if(randEnemy == 10){cout << enemy[10];}
```

can be replaced by:

```
 cout << enemy[randEnemy];
```

Comment: "and you use it like this" – probably not if is a `void` function.

Comment: @Oberon You right, I fixed it, there are many bugs in the original code.

Comment: I used this, but it says there's an error where "Enemy e;" is. it said "Enemy was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @MCE626 I changed `class enemy` to `class Enemy` (with a capital E), since you declared a local variable  `string enemy` in genRandEnemy.

Comment: Yeah i changed that, but it still has dat error thing at "Enemy e;"

Comment: @MCE626 I can't tell why, if it is in other file, maybe you're missing the include? try to copy the class Enemy `class enemy{
    public:
        void genRandEnemy();
};` and paste it before the function.

Comment: hmm.. i think i am... what was that again..?